# Does any inconsistency arise from these two interpretations of $\frac{df}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, soft-question

Using limits, $\dfrac{df(z)}{dx}$ is defined as what the slope of a line joining $(x,f(x))$ and $(x+h,f(x+h))$ approaches as $h \to 0$ which can be rephrased as precisely the slope of the tangent to $f$ at $(x,f(x))$ as the secant would approach the tangent as $h \to 0$. So :
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
Now, we also say that for a very small $\Delta x$ :
$$\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \dfrac{df}{dx} \implies \Delta y = \dfrac{df}{dx}\Delta x$$
Which is actually an approximation but the error is so "negligibly negligible" that it can simply be ignored.

So, the two ways of interpreting $\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}$ are :

Precisely the slope of the tangent to $f$ at $(x,f(x))$ [$0$ error]

The ratio of change in $f(x)$ with an extremely small change in $x$.

The second interpretation is commonly used in Physics and also helps to understand partial derivatives better (for beginners like me, at least). I want to know if these two interpretations go hand in hand or at some point, they give contradicting results and cause inconsistencies. Also, which interpretation should be followed to derive rules like the sum rule, product rule, power rule, quotient rule etc?

Thanks!

Comment: The definition of the derivative follows from the intuitive notion you have written above.

Comment: @PeterForeman Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: @PeterForeman So, first, we thought of the derivative as the rate of change and later on went to define it precisely as the slope of the tangent, right? Why, though? Just to make it rigorous?

Comment: We define the derivative by the limit$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$$if and only if this limit exists. But the expression within the limit is exactly the rate of change through the two points at $(x,f(x))$ and $(x+h,f(x+h))$. As such it makes sense to consider this limit as the "tangential" rate of change.